# How to implement a markerless augmented reality system for mobile devices (Android)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, android-augmented-reality

I am very new to AR technology and Android. I have to implement markerless augmented reality system for mobile devices.(Android). I am little confused with which enviornment or SDK tool to choose. I came across Unity,AR toolkit, vuforia etc. I went through some tutorials on Unity. Please provide some suggestions on how to start with it.which tools or SDK to choose.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is most likely SLAM (Simultaneous localization and mapping)

There are Frameworks like [Kudan](https://www.kudan.eu/), which allow you to implement this. But keep in mind, that this technology is far from being perfectly stable in terms of tracking performance. It will most likely shake like the most camera based tracking solutions do.

Answer (score 0):

Markerless AR may relate to several different things. While it is clear that marker-based SDKs, such as Vuforia, is not what you need, there are a few factors you need to consider. And Unity, by the way, is a platform - so whatever library you decide to use, you will need to consider if Unity suite your needs (assuming that library supports Unity).

I suggest you look here to read about some possible SDKs:

1. [Augmented Reality: Marker vs Markerless AR](http://researchguides.dartmouth.edu/c.php?g=59732&p=382860)
2. [AR frameworks](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/ar-frameworks-388frkga)